# Alternative to using Akka.system inside an object

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I am learning the Play Framework together with Scala, and I looked at the `reactive-stocks` tutorial that comes with `activator` for learning more about the framework.

In the learning project that I am creating (a simple chat) I want to have something similar to this snippet taken out from the tutorial:

```
object StocksActor {
  lazy val stocksActor: ActorRef = Akka.system.actorOf(Props(classOf[StocksActor]))
}
```

That is, an actor that will only be instanciated one time on the application. But I found out that `Akka.system` is deprecated, so I should use dependency injection to get the `ActorSystem`. How would I do dependency injection in an Object?

```
object ChatRoomsActor @Inject() (actorSystem: ActorSystem) {
  lazy val ref: ActorRef = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(classOf[ChatRoomsActor]))
}
```

I tried this code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't inject dependencies in objects. They are already [singletons](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html#companions) and you don't instantiate them. So, what you really need is a `class` instead (`class ChatRoomsActor`) which could be a `@Singleton` (`@Singleton class ClassRoomsActor`).

Comment: hm ok, I'll try to do that, I though with an object was the more "idiomatic" way, since it was written on the tutorial.

Comment: reactive-stocks, it is one of the starting apps from the activator software